# Remove unwanted paragraph space in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

I trying a desktop application for a medical laboratory... There are total 5 table in database 1st one consist of the details of patient....  Like...name....age....sex....lab no....doctor refereed by....date Other four table contains the details regarding the test which patient seeks....  Like...blood test.....urine test...etc I'm coming to the point... What I am trying is that if the patient does not undergoes certain test says urine test then none of the details regarding urine test will be printed I have used iText as IDE to generate the report... Everything is working fine except for the fact that some white space (I guess 4 to 5 paragraph changes) is automatically created whenever a report is generated with a skip of a single test type.
How can I resolve the problem?

Screen Shot Of the Report Generated..
[image]

Screen Shot of my code :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using sub-reports. Are they returning white space even when they are empty? If they are, then the line is never blank.

Look at the "Print When Expression". Can you add a reasonable constraint there? Maybe your main report query can extended to answer which tests have been done - you can then use that info in the "Print When Expression".

It is unusual to put everything into summary band. Put each sub-report in a detail band. With a detail band you have better control over white space between each report. On the detail band you can adjust the "Print When Expression". It will exclude the entire band with white space and all.

Comment: Earlier I had tried to put each sub report in a new detail band. But on doing so I was facing a problem. My 3rd sub report stated to print on new page even though there are lot of space on the page previous page where 2nd sub report is printed. When I tried to find the reason behind it then I came to the fact that if a sub report dont have enough space on the current page then it gets printed on new page.